# Web page (like webmatrix) in mvc3 app

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Could i include a single page .cshtml in a MVC3 app (without controller)? I have some static pages but i like to use our base layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. For example include `index.cshtml` with the following contents in the root of your web site:

```
@DateTime.Now
```

and then navigate to `/index.cshtml`.

Bare in mind that cshtml pages are not allowed in the `~/Views` folder so make sure you don't put outside. The `Views` folder is a special one and is controlled by the `~/Views/web.config` in which the base type for Razor views is changed to  `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` because those are MVC views and also they cannot be served directly.

So you could have 2 types of templates:

- System.Web.WebPages.WebPage (standard WebMatrix WebPage)
- System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage (ASP.NET MVC views, stored in the `~/Views` folder)

This being said, you cannot use your `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` with a WebPage. It can only be used with ASP.NET MVC views.

Comment: yes, you are right. But I want to use a Layout. So that causes a exception.

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: @fravelgue, this is not possible. You cannot mix WebMatrix webpage with ASP.NET MVC views. Your `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` must be served through an `IHttpHandler`.